# Строки с одинаковыми b_id в отдельные столбцы

Tags: mysql

Есть некие строки с одинаковыми b_id, например

```
1 | aa1
1 | aa2
1 | aa3
2 | bb1
2 | bb2
```

После чудотворного SELECT-а нужно получить следующее:

```
1 | aa1 | aa2 | aa3
2 | bb1 | bb2 |
```

Comment: А зачем нужно сие чудо?

Comment: Чтоб решить определенную задачу

Comment: [group_concat](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+group_concat)

Comment: group_concat не решение, оно склеит данные, а не поместит в разные столбцы

Comment: А определённая задача это какая? А если одинаковых id будет 100 то что?

Comment: Зачем придумывать? В данной задаче максимальное число одинаковых b_id 3

Comment: а чем не устраивает group concat? да. будет строка с разделителем. но что мешает её разделить на сервере?

Comment: Я не вижу с ним решение. Может покажете пример запроса, который дает ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 2):

Как вам уже подсказали, можно использовать `GROUP_CONCAT`. А уже на серверe разбивайте эти данные по разделителю.
column2 - имя второй колонки.
table - имя вашей таблицы.

```
SELECT b_id, GROUP_CONCAT(column2 SEPARATOR ' | ') as result FROM `table` GROUP BY b_id
```